# Adding elements from two Sets

Tags: java, int, set

How can I add elements from two sets?

```
If there's a set one (1, 3, 6, 8)
And a set two (2, 4, 6, 8)
```

How do I the elements from those two together?

```
Output should be (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8)
```

Here's what I tried:

```
Set<Integer> one = new HashSet();
one.add(1);
one.add(3);
// and so on
Set<Integer> two = new HashSet();
two.add(2);
two.add(4);
// and so on
Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet();
newSet.add(one);
newSet.add(two);

return newSet;
```

And this doesn't work, as the add method works only for a single integer, not a collection of integer. Is there a method where I can add two sets together?

I also have to return the set. How do I do that?

Comment: try using addAll instead of add

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`Set.addAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
Set<Integer> one = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> two = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>(one);
newSet.addAll(two);
```

Also, you should type your constructors (as above).

To make this into a method, try this:

```
public static Set<Integer> addTwoSets(Set<Integer> one, Set<Integer> two) {
    Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>(one);
    newSet.addAll(two);
    return newSet;
}
```

Let's go nuts... here's a method that will take any number of collections of any type that extends the desired type, and merges them into one set:

```
public static <T> Set<T> merge(Collection<? extends T>... collections) {
    Set<T> newSet = new HashSet<T>();
    for (Collection<? extends T> collection : collections)
        newSet.addAll(collection);
    return newSet;
}
```

Or Java 8+:

```
public static <T> Set<T> merge(Collection<? extends T>... collections) {
    return Arrays.stream(collections).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a Set. As you have discovered, they do not have duplicate elements, by definition. You are looking for a **Multiset** (in fact, a SortedMultiset by the looks of it), also known as a **Bag**. Java doesn't have one out of the box, but there are open source implementations available, for example, [Google's](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

EDIT: Also, you want to do `setOne.addAll(setTwo)`, not one element at a time, as commented above, but that is the secondary problem.

Comment: well, actually I want to later remove the duplicates.

Comment: Ummm, that's definitely NOT what you asked originally, as your sample output has duplicates.

Comment: What's the difference between a *bag* and a *list*?

Comment: A **bag** doesn't have the implicit ordering of a **list**, not in the sense that one element is less than another, but in the sense that it precedes another in the list. Now, a sorted bag could certainly be implemented as an ordered list, but it might be more efficient to use a tree.

Comment: Someone casts a downvote 3.5 years later with no comment? OK…

Answer (score 1):

As Bohemian [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8032613/5136131), the best answer is using Set.addAll(). Just keep in mind that, if you don't mind overwriting one of your sets, it's more efficient (at least from the point of view of the developer's time :P) to add one set directly to another set:

```
one.addAll(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternately use a sorted ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(one);
list.addAll(two);
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: This will not eliminate duplicates.